# Having troubles with if - range command

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having troubles understanding the concept of *for* *in*. I've been checking all the resources I could get into, but all of them are discussing the said command in numerical form

```
# 1st line of code

>>> count = 0
>>> for letter in greeting:
    count +=1
    if count % 2 ==0:
        print(letter)
    print(letter)


H
e
e
l
l
l
o
!
!

# 2nd line of code

>>> count = 0
>>> for letter in greeting:
    count +=2
    if count % 2 ==0:
        print(letter)
    print(letter)


H
H
e
e
l
l
l
l
o
o
!
!

#3rd line of code

>>> count = 0
>>> for letter in greeting:
    count += 3
    if count % 2 == 0:
        print(letter)
    print(letter)


H
e
e
l
l
l
o
!
!
```

Here is what I understand:

on the 2nd code, everything was duplicated, I am not sure why, but I can only assume because the count was == 2 for all of them.

on the 1st and 3rd however, I am not entirely sure how we have come up with the results.

Thank you!

Comment: `bool(0 % 2 == 0) == True`, `bool(2 % 2 == 0) == True`, `bool(4 % 2 == 0) == True`, etc.

Comment: Print `count` along with `letter` to get a better idea of what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the count in every if statement and you'll much better understand what happens:

```
    if count % 2 == 0:
        print(letter + ", count: " + str(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

The % operator in this case is being used to decide if count is perfectly divisible by 2 and doing something as a result. num%2 when num is evenly divided by 2 will return a 0 (0 remainder) while 3%2 returns 1 for example. In the second code, since count is increased by 2 every iteration, it will ALWAYS be divisible by 2 and so the if statement always gets entered.

Answer (score 0):

% operator is used for check reminders and it depends on how you define the iteration as you indicated. For example, the first line of your codes is incremented by 1 for each iteration and so forth to your last line of code. Hope this helps.